# How to split a string into key/value output array for use in later Zapier steps

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, zapier

I have the following string in a Zapier "Run Javascript" action and I need help converting it into an array to "output" for use in later actions.

What I have:

```
meanString = key1: value1, key2: value2
```

What I want (I think):

```
output = {key1: value1, key2: value2 }
```

How do I do that? Thank you in advance. This will open a world of options for us once solved.

Comment: Is the input string "meanString = key1: value1, key2: value2" or "key1: value1, key2: value"?

Comment: Just use `let output = '{' + meanString  + '}'`

Comment: I tried Maheer Ali's suggestion but got the following error from Zapier.  "You must return a single object or array of objects."

Comment: Briosheje the input string is .."key1: value1, key2: value". Thanks